# Database Profile for DBVisualizer & SnappyData?

Tags: dbvisualizer, snappydata

We are using the DBVisualizer Generic profile and Wizard setup to access SnappyData Store, however, the tool randomly loses track of which Driver class to load and then, you need to re-create the connection each time.

Product: DbVisualizer Pro 9.2 [Build #2348]

> An error occurred while establishing the connection: The selected
>   Driver cannot handle the specified Database URL. The most common
>   reason for this error is that the database URL contains a syntax error
>   preventing the driver from accepting it. The error also occurs when
>   trying to connect to a database with the wrong driver. Correct this
>   and try again.

Is there an open source DBVisualizer 'Database Profile' for SnappyData or a better workaround to ensure our Generic DB Connection driver settings remain?

Comment: I am unaware of a profile for DBVisualizer, though I will send this to the team and find out. A member of our community did get SnappyData working with http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/ however.

Comment: OK. Thanks.  Squirrel SQL DB tool works, but our team is all using DBVisualizer for all of our databases, so that it the tool of choice.

Comment: The error at connect indicates that the JDBC URL isn't correct. You also say  you need to re-create it each time. For support please open Help->Contact Support in DbVisualizer to get assistance from the dev team.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to setup DBVisualizer with SnappyData, all I did is created a generic Driver, added the jar file and connected to SnappyDriver , like this jdbc:snappydata://ip:port/
jar file name: snappydata-store-client-1.5.0.jar